# Why does my code not end even when directly prompted to?

Tags: python, infinite

So I have the rest of the code correct, but it doesn't end and I'm unsure why. It shouldn't be infinite because it is prompted when either variable is over 5 to end yet it continues. Any answers?

```
import random
Round = 0
Player_Score = 0
Computer_Score = 0
while Player_Score < 5 or Computer_Score < 5:
    Player_object = input("Would you like to choose R, P, or S?")
    Computer_object = random.sample("RPS", 1)[0]
    if Player_object == "R" or Player_object == "r":
        if Computer_object == "R":
             print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
        elif Computer_object == "P":
            Computer_Score += 1 
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
        else:
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")


    if Player_object == "P" or Player_object == "p":
        if str(Computer_object) == "R":
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
        elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
           print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
        else:
            Computer_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")


    if Player_object == "S" or Player_object == "s":
        if str(Computer_object) == "R":
             print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
        elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
            Computer_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
        else:
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
if Computer_Score == 5 and Player_Score != 5:
    print("The Computer has won!")
if Player_Score == 5 and Computer_Score != 5:
    print("You have won and beaten the computer")
```

Comment: Have you tried tracking your variable values ? With a print for example ?

Comment: You mean `while Player_Score < 5 and Computer_Score < 5` -- `and`, not `or`

Answer (score 1):

Your loop ends when both are higher than 5, if you want it to stop when either are higher then 5 you need to have the following in your main for loop:

```
while Player_Score < 5 and Computer_Score < 5
```